# Dataverse Service Client using certificate (Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client)

Tags: dynamics-crm

I used code example

```
string connectionString = $@"AuthType=Certificate;
                        SkipDiscovery=true;url={myCRM};
                        thumbprint={3 options};
                        ClientId={AppID};
                        RequireNewInstance=true";
```

When Thumbprint was the 3561 characters code, the error was:"One or more errors occurred. (Failed to locate or read certificate from passed thumbprint.)"

when CertThumbprint was the 3561 characters code, the error was:
"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'ClientId or Certificate Thumbprint must be populated for Certificate Auth Type.')"

When Thumbprint was the 40 characters code from Azure , the error was:
"One or more errors occurred. (Keyset does not exist)"

When Thumbprint was the Certificate ID from azure , the error was:"One or more errors occurred. (Failed to locate or read certificate from passed thumbprint.)"

Does someone have an example that works?
Maybe an example for "DataverseServiceClientBuilder"

Thank you